# remove styles from all nodelist element and add only to clicked element Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, nodelist

I have multiple divs that when clicked adds a border and scales them up a little. I am looping through all elements using foreach and on click i remove every element's border and scale property except the clicked element, to which i add a border and scale.
My code is completely logical and is supposed to work but for some reason i cant seem to grasp, it only applies the styles to clicked elements but not removing from the rest of the elements (like my code says it should).

JS

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.projcolorpick div').forEach(el => {
            el.onclick = (e) => {
                el.style.border = "none"
                el.style.transform  = "scale(1)"
                e.target.style.border = "2px solid #fff"
                e.target.style.transform = "scale(1.2)" 
                projcolor = e.target.style.background   
            }
        }) 
     }
```

Comment: you are adding a seprate event listener for each element that. listener fires of an annon function on the el that was clicked... I see nothing about changing the scale for elements outside of each individual event listener... if i'm understanding correctly.

Comment: so how would i remove styles of all other Eléments each time i click on a single element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give something like this a try... each element needs an id attribute for this to work (the filter part - if there is a unique attribute...)

````
    const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.projcolorpick div'));
    list.forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                //code that affects the element you click on
                el.style.border = "2px solid #fff"
                el.style.transform = "scale(1.2)" 
                projcolor = e.target.style.background;
                list.filter(x=>x.id!=el.id).forEach(otherEl=>{
                    //code that affects the other elements you didn't click on
                    otherEl.style.border = "none"
                    otherEl.style.transform  = "scale(1)"
                });
            });
        }); 
     
    ```
edit:
fixed some typos.
````

Comment: each of my ".projcolorpick div" has a unique data attribute how can i use these instead of id?

Comment: in the filter, instead of .id for each x and el. it would be .getAttribute('yourAttribute') for x and el

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` only applies to `Array`s unless you configure it otherwise.

`querySelectorAll` does not return arrays, but array-like objects (NodeLists)

To allow looping over `NodeList`s, add the following code:

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) { 
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}


var nL = document.querySelectorAll('*');

console.log(nL instanceof NodeList); // true
```

Comment: Array.from() is my way around that... not that I am knocking this nifty way of doing it.

Comment: I use my own custom foreach function everywhere lol. Native forEach is good, but you still want to break out of loops sometimes. Want to see it? :-)

Comment: @Kithraya, `Array.every()` is an already existing way of doing a `.forEach()` with the option to break out as soon as you return `false` (or use `Array.some()` if you want to return `true` instead).

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need an `id` attribute on each div and I would advocate using class-assignments instead of changing their individual attributes. You can compare the actual DOM elements with each other like `c==ev.target`, as you can see in my code below:

```js
// === populate the page first ... ============================= START =
const cont=document.getElementById('container');
cont.innerHTML=
[...Array(3)].map(cp=>'<div class="projcolorpick">'+
  [...Array(8)].map(d=>{
    let hsl= "hsl("+Math.floor(Math.random()*360)+",100%,80%)";
    return '  <div style="background-color:'+hsl+'">'+hsl+'</div>'}).join('\n')
  +'</div>').join('\n');
// === populate the page first ... =============================== END =
  
// now, do the action:
cont.onclick=ev=>{
  if (   ev.target.parentNode.classList.contains('projcolorpick')
      && ev.target.tagName=='DIV'){
    [...ev.target.parentNode.children].forEach(c=>c.classList.toggle('selected',c==ev.target));
    ev.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor=ev.target.textContent;
  }
}
```

```css
.projcolorpick {border: 2px solid #888}
.selected {border: 2px solid #fff; transform:scale(1.2);}
div {margin:6px; padding:4px}
.projcolorpick div {width:200px; height:20px}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

The action happens here:

```
cont.onclick=ev=>{
      if (   ev.target.parentNode.classList.contains('projcolorpick')
          && ev.target.tagName=='DIV'){
        [...ev.target.parentNode.children].forEach(c=>c.classList.toggle('selected',c==ev.target));
        ev.target.parentNode.style.backgroundColor=ev.target.textContent;
      }
    }
```

I use a delegated event-attachment to the parent `.container` div. The first `if` statements makes sure that only clicks on `.projcolorpick>div` elements are processed.

> If you want to include more than one generation between them you need to use something like `ev.target.closest('.projcolorpick')` instead ...

Now, inside the `if` block two things happen:

1. Using `toggle()` on all DOM elements in `ev.target.parentNode.children` the class "selected" is either

   - assigned or
   - removed.
2. The text found in the clicked div is applied as `background-color` to the parent `.projcolorpick` container.